# XDocument can't load xml with version 1.1 in C# LINQ?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

`XDocument.Load` throws an exception when using an XML file with version 1.1 instead of 1.0:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Xml.XmlException: Version number '1.1' is invalid. Line 1, position 16.
```

Any clean solutions to resolve the error (without regex) and load the document?

Comment: What's the exception? can you post the xml ?

Comment: The default ConformanceLevel is Document, which according to MSDN states it needs an XML 1.1 document: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h2344bs2.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Initial reaction, just to confirm that I can reproduce this:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Test
{   
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string xml = "<?xml version=\"1.1\" ?><root><sub /></root>";
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        Console.WriteLine(doc);
    }
}
```

Results in this exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Xml.XmlException: Version number '1.1' is invalid. Line 1, position 16.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseXmlDeclaration(Boolean isTextDecl)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(String text, LoadOptions options)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(String text)
   at Test.Main(String[] args)
```

It's still failing as of .NET 4.6.

Comment: The problem is right, do you have a clean solution (No regex).

Comment: I concluded the same... (although I didn't check 4.0; +1 for extra effort)

Comment: Reviewing XmlReader.Create for the XmlReaderSettings, ConformanceLevel.Document states it needs an XML 1.0 document.

Comment: Confirmed still failing in the same way with .NET 4.5 and .NET 4.5.1.

Comment: It fails on .NET 4.6 RC.

Answer (score 5):

"Version 1.0" is hardcoded in various places in the standard .NET XML libraries. For example, your code seems to be falling foul of this line in System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseXmlDeclaration(bool):

```
 if (!XmlConvert.StrEqual(this.ps.chars, this.ps.charPos, charPos - this.ps.charPos, "1.0"))
```

I had a similar issue with XDocument.Save refusing to retain 1.1. It was the same type of thing - a hardcoded "1.0" in a System.Xml method.

I couldn't find anyway round it that still used the standard libraries.

Answer (score 1):

You can just skip the first line, then use XDocument.Parse to load the XML, like this:

```
                var lines = File.ReadAllLines(xmlFilename).ToList();
                lines[0] = String.Empty;
                var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(string.Join("", lines));
```